# Does Datomic retrieve all data to the local system (Peer) before running a query?

Tags: performance, datomic

"Datomic queries run in application process space" : does that mean that all the data the query has to run on has to be local, too? Let's say I am running a join on two tables, each of which are 1 GB in size, does Datomic first retrieve 2 GB of data to the Peer on which the query is going to run?

Excuse me if this question is already answered in the documentation and I should RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding only the live index is provided for the query to run. With the help of the index only relevant data need to be fetched from the storage service, but only if it is not yet available in the local cache.

Answer (score 1):

The data does not reside on the peers, only the indexes. When you run a query, the peer traverses the most suitable index to find the nodes that need to be retrieved from the storage service. Thus the actual query from the peer to the storage service only requests the id's that were reached in the query of the index. The index sizes can be quite large depending on how much data you have stored, but it will only retrieve from the storage service, the data it needs.

Datomic does not have the notion of table joins, so I'm interested to know exactly what you mean here; different partitions or databases?

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your question : I just mean things which traditionally fall into the foreign key-primary key inner join scenario. Not sure if they would be different partitions or DBs. Maybe I'll update with a more intelligent question as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **No**.

Datomic maintains several indexes, each sorted by different criteria. Each of these indexes is split into segments, with every segment containing thousands of data items (datoms). That's right, the data itself is contained in the index.

When doing a query, **Datomic will retrieve only those index segments that it needs to perform the query**. As indexes are sorted, Datomic can figure out which segments it needs. As it retrieves index data in segment units, it will always contain some data that you are not interested in - but this seems to be a pretty good tradeoff to tackle management and communication overhead and will boost performance in practice.

**In all typical queries, no *full database scan* is necessary.** In cases where it is necessary, the peer will indeed have to pull in all data to the local system. However, this does not mean that all data will reside in memory at the same time at one point - unless your query result contains all data - because Datomic will garbage collect segments once processed and not necessary any more, in case memory is scarce.

That said, the [order of where clauses in queries is important for performance](http://docs.datomic.com/query.html#sec-7-1), although I can't say if the order affects the number of index segments retrieved.

More on indexes can be found on [Datomic indexes page](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html) and on Nikita Prokopov's  [Unofficial guide to Datomic internals](http://tonsky.me/blog/unofficial-guide-to-datomic-internals/).